# Cordova Contact with Database

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, foreach, asp.net-web-api2

Below is my code which consist of **Javascript** and **WebAPI**,I am trying to check the local phone contacts   with my Database.I am using **Cordova Contact API** to get all local **phoneNumber** and **Name**.I am storing **phonenumber** and **name**  separately in two different array variable and passing that to WEBAPI through ajax has show in below code.In C# I am comparing local phonenumber with phoneNumber which is in database,If the phone number is exist in database i am keeping it in **existUserContact** variable,if the phone number is not exist in database i am keeping it in **numbersThatNotExistsInDB** variables.Now if phoneNumber exist it database i ll get username from database its working fine.But if the number is not exisit in database i need to bind the same  name which is in local phoneContact name which i am getting from **NameCollection** to particular notexist Number.how i can bind particular name which i am stored in **NameCollection**  for **numbersThatNotExistsInDB** kindly suggest

```
 //cordova Contact API Success function//
function onSuccess(contacts) {
if (contacts.length != 0) {
    // get formatted names and sort
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; ++i) {
        if (contacts[i].name) {
            if (contacts[i].name.formatted) 
         //Storing names in names array variable//
        names.push(contacts[i].name.formatted.trim());
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; ++i) {
        if (contacts[i].phoneNumbers) {
            if (contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value)
    //Storing phoneNumber in phoneNumberContactCollection array variable//
     phoneNumberContactCollection.push(contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value); }
    } }}

//Through ajax function i am passing my all phone numbers and names to webapi //
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({Names:names,mobileNumber: phoneNumberContactCollection, deviceUUID: self.DeviceUUID }),
        url: serverUrl + 'xx/xxx/GetContacts',
        success: function (data) { }

[HttpPost]
public  IHttpActionResult GetContacts(JObject jsonData)
 {
   dynamic json = jsonData;
   string deviceUID = json.deviceUUID;
   string[] mobilenumber =json.mobilecollection.ToObject<string[]>();
   string[]NameCollection= json.nameCollection.ToObject<string[]>();
   var getContacts=  xxx.getAllcontacts(mobilenumber,deviceUID,NameCollection);
   return ok(getContacts); 
} 

public List<ContactList> getAllcontacts(string[]mobilenumberCollection, string deviceUID,string[] NameCollection)
    {
    try
        {
        List<ContactList> MobileContact = new List<ContactList>();
        List<string> mobileNumbers = new List<string>();
        List<string> ContactName = new List<string>();
        if (deviceUID != null)
            {
            var existdevice = dbContext.DeviceInformation.FirstOrDefault(u => u.deviceUUID == deviceUID);
            if (existdevice != null)
                {
                var existuser = dbContext.UserTable.FirstOrDefault(u => u.deviceID == existdevice.deviceId);
                if (existuser.userId != 0 && existuser.IsActive == true && mobilenumberCollection != null)
                    {
                    foreach (var item in mobilenumberCollection)
                        {                                 
                            mobileNumbers.Add(mobile);
                            }
                        }
                    foreach (var contactName in NameCollection)
                        {
                        ContactName.Add(contactName);
                        }
 //Here i am checking the phoneNumbers which exist in Database
                    var existUserContact = dbContext.UserTable.Where(m => mobileNumbers.Contains(m.mobileNumber)).Distinct().ToList();
      //Here  the phoneNumbers which Not exist in Database
                    var numbersThatNotExistsInDB = mobileNumbers.Where(n => !existUserContact.Any(a => a.mobileNumber == n)).ToList();


                    if (existUserContact != null)
                        {

                        foreach (var MobileNumberExsitDB in existUserContact)                                  
                           {
                            ContactList contactList = new ContactList();
                            if (existuser.userId!=MobileNumberExsitDB.userId)
                                {


                                    contactList.userId = MobileNumberExsitDB.userId;

                                    contactList.userName = MobileNumberExsitDB.userName;
                                    contactList.userProfileImageBase64 = MobileNumberExsitDB.userImageBase64;
                                    contactList.userProfileImagetype = MobileNumberExsitDB.userImagetype;
                                    MobileContact.Add(contactList);
                                    }
                                }    }
                        }
                    if (numbersThatNotExistsInDB != null)
                        {

                        foreach (var NotExistnumber in numbersThatNotExistsInDB)
                            {
                            foreach (var NotExist in ContactName)
                                {
                           ContactList phonenumber = new ContactList();
                            phonenumber.mobileNumber = NotExistnumber;
                            phonenumber.userName = NotExist;

                            MobileContact.Add(phonenumber);
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        return MobileContact;
        }
    catch (Exception)
        {

        throw new Exception("Server Busy! Please try after some time. 309");
        }


    }
```